# What is a good regular expression to match if 2 URLs start in the same way?

Tags: javascript, regex

I would like to check if 2 urls start in the same way.
I am using:

```
let regexpUrl = "https://www.example.com/fr/article/".replace(/\//g, "\\/");
let matchUrl1OK = "https://www.example.com/fr/article/".match(regexpUrl)
let matchUrl2OK = "https://www.example.com/fr/article/page.html".match(regexpUrl)
```

I am not very fluent in regular expressions, so I'm not sure that this is the best solution.

Comment: Are you sure you need a regex? Would `.indexOf()` suffice?

Comment: `start in the same way` => how many chars ?

Comment: Can you not use `string2.startsWith(string1.substring(0, 10))`?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Location

Comment: @David, No, I'm not sure I need a regex.

Comment: @Thomas Ayoub , no limits, they're strings.

Comment: @Fran, That is an example. I need to check many strings (containing Urls) with different lengths of characters

Comment: What everybody is trying to say is that you need to define a number of chars, or it may not work as you expect, example: beggining of all three strings you provided matches, they all starts with `h`. How an algorithm will know how much chars it has to check ??

Comment: I misspoke. `regexpUrl` is the model string. I need to check that all other strings start with `regexpUrl`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To check if a string `url` starts with `regexpUrl`, Do `url.startsWith(regexpUrl)`

Comment: To ignoring the case I do `url.toLowerCase().startsWith(regexpUrl.toLowerCase())`